# issue in installing and working with phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have downloaded and installed node.js in my system and when i try to install phonegap with the command

D:>npm install -g phonegap

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.2.1 (x64) and npm.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.2.1 (x64) and npm.

```
C:\Users\536351>d:
D:\>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade
 to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o
n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible
. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.
1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 407
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.
1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 407
fetchMetadata -> fetch    | |############-------------------------------------|
```

tis is wat I get... Can someone help me out with tis?

Comment: I think phonegap is now cordova try `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: No... not yet ... still figuring